# How to create 301 or 302 redirect in PrestaShop 1.7?

Tags: .htaccess, seo, prestashop, redirect, prestashop-1.7

I have a **Prestasop 1.7** based store. I changed a product URL. People can find this product from Google. But they can't access the product page, because the product page URL has changed. So I need to add **301 redirect rule** for **old URL** to **new URL**. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two ways to do that, edit the .htaccess (if you have apache based web server) or to install a module.

If you choose the .htaccess, create a 301 redirect is quite simple, here an example:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Redirect 301 /old-cat/old-url.html http://www.youdomain.com/new-cat/new-url.html
</ifModule>
```

Insert this rule before the rules of PrestaShop.
More info [here](https://www.rapidtables.com/web/dev/htaccess-redirect.html)

The other way, the module, you can install a module like [this](https://addons.prestashop.com/en/url-redirects/11399-301-302-303-url-redirects-and-404-seo.html) that simplify the operation.

UPDATE: 
Like @Agah Toruk says

It's a better option to disable the product and create the same product as a new product instead of changing the product URL. In this way, you can redirect the old product to the new product in product editing page easily.

[image: Redirection settings in product editing page]

Enojoy

Answer (score 1):

It's a better option to disable the product and create the same product as a new product instead of changing the product URL. In this way, you can redirect the old product to the new product in product editing page easily.

[image: Redirection settings in product editing page]

Comment: Yes, It's a valid alternative if you can do that, usually when there isn't synchronization with software or other stuff ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any module or htaccess line in this case.
Just activate the canonical redirect in parameters > SEO. Canonical redirect are made for this need.

Hope it helps